# Kind of popular variation in Tournament

Tags: opening, tournament, transpositions, houdini

I am just an ordinary chess player who does not know about Chess **Tournament** even just a little thing,

as I saw at my Houdini vs my Houdini at **Tournament** level in 5 minutes 
(and now I still testing in infinite time [based on ***maximum search depth***].. and will move when depth reaches 99. [believe me, it's really deep]),

in early (at 3 games) seem  to be played and transposed to **`Benoni variation`**, 
are there some information that in the real **Tournament**, it is often to happened too??

**if it is not,**

what kind of variation which seem to be played in any **Tournament**, 
because I want to learn opening and it's transposed to another which was proved and tested in **Tournament** first.. ^^

Thanks, 
Ahmad

Comment: This question is very hard to understand as written. It's not clear what you're asking. Perhaps you can work with people here to turn it into a clear question.

Comment: as [@Andrew-ng](http://chess.stackexchange.com/users/1382/andrew-ng) said, [it helps](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/how-to-test-the-quality-of-an-opening-book/2432#2432) even just a little bit.. It needs more work around now.. ^^.. thanks to all viewer and for the appreciation..

Comment: my houdini **'not properly flows'** even still counting node at approx. over **`214 Billion Node`**. And it show current value at node approx. over **`166 Billion Node`** with Indian variation (`1. d4 Nf6` `2. c4 e6` `...`). So I will suspended my research now..  thanks to all viewer and for the appreciation..

Comment: now, I can control my houdini **(_after restart_)** and still counting node at approx. over `391 Billion Node`. And it show current value at node approx. over `285 Billion Node` with **(`1. d4 Nf6` `2. Nf3 e6` `3. c4 b6` `4. a3 Bb7` `5. Bf4 Be7`)**. May be it sound just crazy but I just want to share this to all viewer and thanks for the appreciation.. ^^–

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** You seem to be concerned if the opening is "tournament tested." I can affirm that almost all of the mainstream openings are well-tested, and you can figure out what these are yourself by doing the appropriate research online (i.e, which openings are most commonly played. See the links I supplied with [this post](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/2432/1382).)

---

It would be great if you could clarify your exact question, but I feel as if you're asking if the Benoni Defense is a respectable opening. The Benoni positions arise after:

```
[FEN ""]
    1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5
```

And here Black can play the Benko Gambit with `3...b5`or go into more typical Benoni lines with `3...e6`. Of course, there are many other moves that can transpose into Benoni positions.

As for its reputation, the Benoni is certainly playable at all levels and has been played in World Championship matches. However, in recent times, the Benoni has been considered inferior to other Indian/Hypermodern defenses against the Queen Pawn openings such as the Grünfeld or Queen's Indian.

A few years ago at a coaching seminar in New York City, former World Champion Garry Kasparov remarked (perhaps jokingly) to my friend who played the Benoni that he should find a "real opening." That being said, Tal and Fischer employed the Benoni in the middle of the 20th century, with the former [winning several brilliant games in the 1950s and 1960s](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/ezsearch.pl?search=tal%20benoni) and the latter winning a key game in the [1972 World Championship Match against Spassky](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1044727).

You can read more about the Benoni Defense [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benoni_Defense).